# Meteor: hide/show template on Mongo DB query

Tags: javascript, mongodb, templates, meteor

I am looking for a way (or ways) to show or hide Meteor Handlebars html template based on the status of Mongo DB variable.  In other words, if a user submits a rating for a particular pun, then that rating is stored in a Mongo collection and the 'rating' template should hide itself.  Therefore the "hide" could be triggered by a number of conditions, such as right after a user submits a rating for the first time, or at onload if the user happens to load a previously-rated pun.

My initial attempt at using Session seems to have missed the mark or something is not clicking.

Javascript

```
Session.setDefault('rated', 'notRated');

function ratingDisplay () {
  var whetherRated = userHasRated();
  // userHasRated() is a function that returns boolean 'true' is the user has rated or boolean 'false' if not
  if (whetherRated === true) {
    Session.set('rated', 'rated');
  } else {
    Session.set('rated', 'notRated');
  }
}

Handlebars.registerHelper('isRated', function (input) {
  return Session.get('rated');
});

UI.body.helpers({
  isRated: function (rating) {
    return Session.equals('rated', rating);
  }
});
```

HTML: the three lines beginning with {{/if isRated 'notRated'}} is where the trouble lies.

```
<template name="ShowTake">
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="item">take a pun</h1>
      {{#with randomPun}}
        <p class="item">{{prompt}}</p>
        <p class="item">{{answer}}</p>
      {{/with}}
      {{#if isRated 'notRated'}}
        {{> Rating}}
      {{/if}}
    <button class="item btn" data-action="getPun">more pun</button>
    <button class="item btn clickChangesPage" data-page="showMain">return</button>
  </div>
</template>
```

After testing, I've determined that the 'Rating' template shows regardless of the state of Session variable 'rated'. Any thoughts are welcome. Also, if I have way over-complicated the issue, I am certainly open to more elegant answers.

Answer (score 0):

First of all why dont instead of `notRated` and `rated`, you use `true` / `false`?

Something like `Session.setDefault('rated', false');`

Then make something like this.

```
Tracker.autorun(function(){
  Session.set('rated', userHasRated()); //since this returns true or false
});
```

Then you can do a helper like this.

```
Template.ShowTake.helpers({
 isRated: function(){
  return Session.get(); //or use a RegisterHelper 
 }
});
```

Then your if will look like this.

```
{{#if isRated }}
    {{> Rating}}
{{/if}}
```